# How do I redirect to a specific page depending on the received variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have 2 pages from where you can input text and it gets sent to a single page called newposts. What can I do to redirect to the page from which I had submitted the data? For eg: How do I post something from one page so that when I submit it, it should  redirect it  back to the  page I submitted the  data from?

Comment: Your explanation is abit twisted. Did you mean that when you submit that data from your html page to your php page, that same data is then sent back from the php page to the same html page that sent it?

Comment: Your question is lacking a bit of clarity but I think I understood it and submitted an answer. Please take the time to make your question a bit clearer for other users since question and answers are online to help others which are faced to the same problem.

Comment: Can you share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes thanks for the help. So I used $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER] and it has solved my problem. Thanks again it really did solve my issue. Sorry if the problem wasn't clearly described as it was my first time asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you have 2 pages, let's say for example:

- *your-site.com/page-one*
- *your-site.com/page-two*

Both of them contain a `<form>` with the `name` and `name2` inputs. Both will post to the same PHP script, let's say at *your-site.com/submit-name*.

Well, if your submission URL is handled with some PHP then you have several options:

### A) Read the HTTP referer header

When you click on a link or submit a form, the browser normally sends the URL from where it comes. This is the HTTP referer header. In PHP, you can get it like this:

```php
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
```

You could then use it after your processing to redirect the user back there.
I would just validate that it comes from your site and not from anywhere. This check should be done because anybody could create a `<form>` with the *action* attribute pointing to your submission URL. In this case, you should NOT handle the submission except if it's what you want.

### B) Add a hidden input field with the info from where you come

If you don't want to read the HTTP referer header, you could also add a hidden form input with an information that your PHP script could use to redirect to the corresponding page. Example:

```html
<form action="/submit-form" method="POST">
  <div class="column">
    <!-- Send info to know where you should redirect to. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="page-one">

    <!-- build_id should change to prevent from CSRF -->
    <input type="hidden" name="build_id" value="78934hBvcdWes343">

    <!-- The rest of your form: -->
    <input name="name" placeholder="Your name">
    <input name="name2" placeholder="Type your name again">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Security good practices

I just added a build id (also known as form token) in your form. It's not part of your question and isn't mandatory, it's just a good practice. The idea is that when you are handling data from the user, typically to change the user's name or do what ever regarding his personal data, you should protect yourself against [cross site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). This can be done by using `POST` instead of `GET` and by storing a random generated value in the user's session that you insert in a hidden input of your forms. When you recieve the submission, you compare what you recieved with what you have in your session. If they don't match then you should not handle the submission. Checking the referer will also improve security.

### PHP redirection

In PHP, to tell the browser to redirect to another page, you should just do:

```php
<?php

header('Location: https://your-site.com/page-one');
exit;
```

So, typically, create a constant or defined value for your root website URL and then build the location URL with your validation steps and logic.

You could also use `$_SERVER` to rebuild the URL dynamically from the protocol and server name. Just be carefull that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` could possibly be something else than your own website domain name since an attacker can address a request to your server by sending another hostname header. If your site is the default web site of the server then your redirection could point to the attackers domain instead of yours. But in most cases, if you are hosting your site on a mutualized server then this cannot happen because your domain is a virtual host and the default virtual host should normally be an empty page set by the hosting company.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help. I had manged to resolve it using HTTP_REFERER  to redirect it to its source page.